# All data except for fileName disappears from fileDetails in a couple of days after uploading the video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube Data API (v3) to access my own video info.
Everything worked fine, I could get `fileDetails.fileSize`, `fileDetails.videoStreams[]` etc. as I expected. 
However, in a couple of days after I uploaded the video, the same API returns only `fileDetails.fileName` and no other info anymore.

Now returned json looks like this:

```
"fileDetails": {
  "fileName": "test movie.mp4"
}
```

Here is my request URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=fileDetails&id=__my_video_id__
```

The video is owned by my account with which I did OAuth and got an access token.

I tried the URL on OAuth 2.0 Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), but I got the same result though once it returned all data when I tried it on the day I uploaded the video.

I wonder it might be related to the video visibility since I set it to `unlisted` so that others won't find my test video by searching.

Any info is welcome!

---

**Edited:**

The video itself doesn't have any problem. I can play it on YouTube and via YouTube iframe API also.

Comment: Have you checked if the `processingDetails.fileAvailability` property has a value of **available**? The `fileDetails` object will only be returned if this property has a value.

Comment: @jess, you are right! `processingDetails.fileAvailability` returns `terminated` now. Do you know any reason why the availability becomes `terminated`?

Comment: The strange point is, it should have been processed successfully once, otherwise I shouldn't be able to retrieve fileDetails at all. For some reason, at some point, the availability changes to `terminated` :-(

Comment: It means that the channel was terminated due to various factors like copyright claim, invalid clicks, Community guidelines strikes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware that YouTube has a system which automatically detects copyright infringements, however, this issue seems to happen randomly even when we don't violate any copyright of others. (happens with our original videos too)

We finally decided to cache `fileDetail` on our backend.